# Android: How to create a Dialog without a title?

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog

I'm trying to generate a custom dialog in Android. 
I create my Dialog like this:

```
dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);
```

Everythings works fine except for the title of the Dialog.
Even if I don't set the title of the dialog the dialog popup has a blank space at the position of the dialog.

Is there any way to hide this part of the Dialog?

I tried it with an AlertDialog but it seems the layout is not set properly:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = 
    (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_dialog, null);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(view);

// dialog = new Dialog(this);
// dialog.setContentView(R.layout.map_dialog);

dialog = builder.create();

((TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.nr)).setText(number);
```

If I use this code I get a null Pointer Exception in the last line.  The dialog is not null so the TextView I try to retrieve does not exist.
If I uncomment the part where I use the Dialog Constructor everything works fine but for the title above my dialog layout.

Comment: @Janusz rechoose your answer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/3407871/632951

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263639/android-dialog-removing-title-bar instead of the previous answer...simple answer

Comment: Just do not call AlertDialog.Builder.setTitle() and your dialog will appear without a title.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

You can hide the title of a dialog using:

`dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

---

Previous version of this answer, which is overcomplicated:

You need to use an `AlertDialog`. There's a good explanation on the Android Developer's site about [custom dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog).

In very short summary, you do this with code like copied below from the official website. That takes a custom layot file, inflates it, gives it some basic text and icon, then creates it. You'd show it then with `alertDialog.show()`.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
        mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,
        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Hello, this is a custom dialog!");
ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);

builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setView(layout);
alertDialog = builder.create();
```

In response to comment:

I assume that TextView with the id `nr` is in the View you are inflating with `View view = inflater....`. If so, then you need to change just one bit: instead of `dialog.findView...` make it `view.findView...`. Then once you've done that, remember to use dialog.show(), or even builder.show() without bothering to do builder.create().

Comment: I think you may have misread the Question? Janusz already has the custom dialog displaying and just requires information on removing the title

Comment: Well, according to the official documentation, "A dialog made with the base Dialog class must have a title. If you don't call setTitle(), then the space used for the title remains empty, but still visible. If you don't want a title at all, then you should create your custom dialog using the AlertDialog class." I haven't personally experimented with it, but that would suggest that even using a custom dialog layout or themes, it's impossible to remove the title space.

Comment: 2nd thought: I think we're understanding "title" differently. I assume he's talking about the space at the top of the pop-up window, not the title at the top of the app.

Comment: Not sure, I have an activity in my application with a dialog theme so it appears like a dialog and the code in my answer removes the space at the top of the pop up. I believe I done the same successfully for a custom dialog as in the question but I dont have the code at the min so cant be sure and may not be correct.

Comment: Ok good try but it is not working. I get: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application 

if I want to shwo the dialog.

Comment: Edit your question and show us the code you used. The above principle works, I've done it myself, so you must have done something wrong in your implementation. Also, did you read the developer's website instructions or did you just copy/paste?

Comment: I have added more info to my answer regarding your new issue, report back if that helps or not

Comment: Still now working. The problem is that in the custom dialog page you linked is a title shown that is not created through their xml file. It seems that every dialog needs this title...

Comment: Thanks for the work and trying all that. view.findViewById is working and the dialog has no title.

Comment: @SteveHaley, No it is possible to hide it using the following line `dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); `

Comment: Make sure you do dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); BEFORE you inflate your dialog view.

Comment: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Answer (score 586):

FEATURE_NO_TITLE works when creating a dialog from scratch, as in:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

But it doesn't work when creating an AlertDialog (or using the Builder), because it already disables the title and use a custom one internally.

I have looked at the SDK sources, and I think that it can't be worked around. So to remove the top spacing, the only solution is to create a custom dialog from scratch IMO, by using the Dialog class directly.

Also, one can do that with a style, eg in styles.xml:

```
<style name="FullHeightDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And then:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.FullHeightDialog);
```

Comment: Instead of creating a custom dialog from scratch, I created the styles.xml as suggested by oliverg. And then, I added 
android:theme="@style/FullHeightDialog"
to the <activity>...</acitivity> declaration in the Manifest file. It just worked. Thanks..

Comment: @olivierg but I want a button with a full height dialog. what's the solution?

Comment: **Note** the line requestWindowFeature must be **BEFORE** the setContentView line.

Comment: While this answers the actual comments best, the solution in the accepted answer is the best in my opinion. I started out doing it like this, with a clean `Dialog`, but creating an `AlertDialog` was a lot easier. As it is stated in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog): `The Dialog class is the base class for dialogs, but you should avoid instantiating Dialog directly. Instead, use one of the following subclasses: <AlertDialog and others described here>`. The `AlertDialog` also handles lifecycle stuff and ok/cancel in easy manners.

Answer (score 67):

In your code add this line

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Or in XML use a theme

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

XML would be a better implementation as with the code version the title bar gets created and then removed which is a waste of resource

> Ok good try but it is not working. I
>   get:
>   android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException:
>   Unable to add window -- token null is
>   not for an application if I want to
>   shwo the dialog.

Change the alert dialog type to system dialog ( e.g., TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY ) and see if this resolves your issue

Answer (score 61):

Use like this:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

This will remove any title bar from dialog window.

Comment: How do I bring it back later?

Answer (score 57):

Use below code before `setcontentview` :-

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
```

**Note**: You must have above code, in same order and line.
 `requestWindowFeature` must be **before** the setContentView line.

Comment: When using in a Dialogfragment, this solution works better for me as the accepted answer creates a tiny vertical gap between the dialog frame and inner content view.

Answer (score 38):

you can remove title by

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

where dialog is name of my dialog .

Answer (score 29):

In your code if you use `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`  be sure that it goes before `dialog.setContentView();` otherwise it causes the application to crash.

Comment: rather doubt to try before and quite surprised that it obviously works. since in android.developer.com they said clearly that it's a must for a custom dialog to have a title. :P

Answer (score 10):

In your Custom_Dialog.java class add `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)`

```
public class Custom_Dialog extends Dialog {

    protected Custom_Dialog(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //This line 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me... for some reason all the other suggestions did not work.  The only thing I would recommend is to make the constructor public and also to provide the other Dialog constructor that only takes a Context

Answer (score 10):

I found Three Way to do this >

1) Using requestWindowFeature

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(dialog.getWindow().FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

2) Using style (style.xml)

```
<style name="FullHeightDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.FullHeightDialog);
```

3) Using XML theme in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Comment: Method one should be 
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Answer (score 7):

[olivierg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3407871/445348) worked for me and is the best solution if creating a custom Dialog class is the route you want to go.  However, it bothered me that I couldn't use the AlertDialog class. I wanted to be able to use the default system AlertDialog style. Creating a custom dialog class would not have this style.

So I found a solution (hack) that will work without having to create a custom class, you can use the existing builders.

The AlertDialog puts a View above your content view as a placeholder for the title. If you find the view and set the height to 0, the space goes away.

I have tested this on 2.3 and 3.0 so far, it is possible it doesn't work on every version yet.

Here are two helper methods for doing it:

```
/**
 * Show a Dialog with the extra title/top padding collapsed.
 * 
 * @param customView The custom view that you added to the dialog
 * @param dialog The dialog to display without top spacing
     * @param show Whether or not to call dialog.show() at the end.
 */
public static void showDialogWithNoTopSpace(final View customView, final Dialog dialog, boolean show) {
    // Now we setup a listener to detect as soon as the dialog has shown.
    customView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Check if your view has been laid out yet
            if (customView.getHeight() > 0) {
                // If it has been, we will search the view hierarchy for the view that is responsible for the extra space. 
                LinearLayout dialogLayout = findDialogLinearLayout(customView);
                if (dialogLayout == null) {
                    // Could find it. Unexpected.

                } else {
                    // Found it, now remove the height of the title area
                    View child = dialogLayout.getChildAt(0);
                    if (child != customView) {
                        // remove height
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
                        lp.height = 0;
                        child.setLayoutParams(lp);

                    } else {
                        // Could find it. Unexpected.
                    }
                }

                // Done with the listener
                customView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
         }

    });

    // Show the dialog
    if (show)
             dialog.show();
}

/**
 * Searches parents for a LinearLayout
 * 
 * @param view to search the search from
 * @return the first parent view that is a LinearLayout or null if none was found
 */
public static LinearLayout findDialogLinearLayout(View view) {
    ViewParent parent = (ViewParent) view.getParent();
    if (parent != null) {
        if (parent instanceof LinearLayout) {
            // Found it
            return (LinearLayout) parent;

        } else if (parent instanceof View) {
            // Keep looking
            return findDialogLinearLayout((View) parent);

        }
    }

    // Couldn't find it
    return null;
}
```

Here is an example of how it is used:

```
    Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setView(yourCustomView)
        .create();

    showDialogWithNoTopSpace(yourCustomView, dialog, true);
```

If you are using this with a DialogFragment, override the DialogFragment's `onCreateDialog` method. Then create and return your dialog like the first example above. The only change is that you should pass false as the 3rd parameter (show) so that it doesn't call show() on the dialog.  The DialogFragment will handle that later.

Example:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
        .setView(yourCustomView)
        .create();

    showDialogWithNoTopSpace(yourCustomView, dialog, false);
    return dialog;
}
```

As I test this further I'll be sure to update with any additional tweaks needed.

Comment: Elegant solution, +1. Do you know how to use this in a DialogFragment?

Comment: @Binoy updated the answer for DialogFragments (that is actually how I personally use it)

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this question is still actual, but in my case, when I switched from Dialog to DialogFragment,

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

was not an option, but I could use

```
setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
```

instead with the same result.

Comment: To clarify, this line (`setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);`) will go in the onCreate method of your DialogFragment class.

Answer (score 4):

Set the title to empty string using builder.

```
    Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("");
...
    builder.show();
```

Answer (score 3):

set the "gravity" attribute on the entire dialog to "center".  Then you will need to override that setting to all of the child components in the dialog that you do not want centered.

Answer (score 3):

```
dialog=new Dialog(YourActivity.this, 1);  // to make dialog box full screen with out title.
dialog.setContentView(layoutReference);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layoutexample);
```

Answer (score 3):

in XML use a theme

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 3):

If we simply use the dialog without the `setTitle()`,then is that gonna work in removing the space of the title ?

```
mUSSDDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setView(dialogView)
.setPositiveButton(R.string.send_button,DialogListener)
.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,DialogListener)
.setCancelable(false).create();
```

Answer (score 3):

Think you can just use this now:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
  .setView(view)
  .setTitle("")
  .create()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", 
                             "Loading. Please wait...", true);
```

creates a title less dialog

Answer (score 2):

```
public static AlertDialog showAlertDialogWithoutTitle(Context context,String msg) 
     {
      AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
      alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(msg).setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

         }
        });

       return alertDialogBuilder.create(); 
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

While using AlertDialog, not using `setTitle()` makes the title disappear

Answer (score 1):

After a bunch of hacking, I got this to work:

```
            Window window = dialog.getWindow();
            View view = window.getDecorView();
            final int topPanelId = getResources().getIdentifier( "topPanel", "id", "android" );
            LinearLayout topPanel = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(topPanelId);
            topPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: what is `dialog` over here and `getResources()`

Answer (score 1):

You Can do this without using `AlertDialog` by defining new Class that extends from `Dialog` Class like this:

```
public class myDialog extends Dialog {
    public myDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's something you can do with `AlertBuilder` to make the title disappear:

```
TextView title = new TextView(this);
title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
builder.setCustomTitle(title);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.image_show_dialog_layout);
```

Answer (score 1):

dialog_custom .requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

this will remove title from cutsom dialog.

Note add these line before adding content.. for eg

```
     dialog_custom = Dialog(activity!!)
    dialog_custom.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    dialog_custom.setContentView(R.layout.select_vehicle_type)
    dialog_custom.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
    dialog_custom.setCancelable(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I try requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
**but not working** for me, if you are like me **so do this** :

Passing a theme to your dialog can remove the title bar for you.

```
    <style name="NoTitleDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Pass the theme to your dialog:

Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.NoTitleDialog);

that's it very simple