# Popup window size in android

Tags: android, layout, popup, size

I'm creating a popup window in a listactivity in the event onListItemClick.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View pop = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popupcontact, null, false);
ImageView atnot = (ImageView)pop.findViewById(R.id.aNot);
height = pop.getMeasuredHeight();
width = pop.getMeasuredWidth();
Log.e("pw","height: "+String.valueOf(height)+", width: "+String.valueOf(width));
atnot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pw.dismiss();
    }
});

 pw = new PopupWindow(pop, width, height, true);

 // The code below assumes that the root container has an id called 'main'
 //pw.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); 
 pw.showAsDropDown(v, 10, 5);
```

Now, the height and width variables were supposed to be height and width of the layout used for the popup window (popupcontact). But they return 0. I guess that is because the layout isn't rendered yet. Does anyone have a clue, how can I control the size of the popup window without needing to use absolute pixel numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your code will work because you are trying to get the width and height of the view that is a child of your popup window.

Since you are anchoring the popupwindow to the "v" view, maybe set the width and height according to the anchor view (or at a ratio based on them)?

Answer (score 45):

I had a similar issue. I solved it by calling:

```
pop.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
```

before getting the size of the layout with getMeasuredHeight() and getMeasuredWidth()

Comment: Am also facing the same issue. This works, but giving less height that the original

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a Popup window take a look at the [Creating Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). 
If you want to use a complete own View in your dialog have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644134/android-how-to-create-a-dialog-without-a-title) make sure to read the comments on the accepted answer. I think there is no need to use PopupWindow yourself to create this view and the dialog stuff will get you to a result much easier.

If you want to stick with the PopupWindow and you don't want to change the width and height of your window just use another [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#PopupWindow%28android.view.View%29) for PopupWindow there are some available that don't need height and width. They don't take a boolean for the ability to focus the window but it seems you can change this later on via [setFocusable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setFocusable%28boolean%29).