# Android Dialog: Removing title bar

Tags: android, layout, dialog

I have a weird behavior I can't pinpoint the source of.

I have my app with the classic

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

to remove the title/status bar.

I then create a Dialog box to allow the user to enter information (name etc)

With a physical keyboard, no problem but when I use the virtual keyboard I have a strange behavior:

each time I hit a key on the virtual key board the title/status bar reappears pushing all the keyboard layout around then vanishes again (just like the animation of when I start the application)

here is some code :

```
        dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.logindialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Login:");

        WindowManager.LayoutParams a = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();

//      dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        a.dimAmount = 0;
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(a);

        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

and then

```
dialog.show();
```

I tried

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

but it crashes my app.

here is the xml

```
    <TextView android:id="@+id/LoginText"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login:">
    </TextView>         
    <EditText android:id="@+id/LoginEdit"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="jason"
        android:layout_width="200sp"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/PasswordText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Password:">
    </TextView>         
    <EditText android:id="@+id/PasswordEdit"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="welcome"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:password="true"/>
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/test2"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button android:id="@+id/LoginButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Login" />
<Button android:id="@+id/CreateButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Create" />
<Button android:id="@+id/CancelLogin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Cancel" />
</LinearLayout>/>
```

Comment: Post your logcat when you use dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 also while using above line of code dont use dialog.setTitle("Login:");

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but its not the problem. what happens is when I type something with the keyboard, the status bar keeps appearing and disappearing with each key stroke.

Answer (score 441, accepted):

use,

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //before     
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.logindialog);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but its not the problem. what happens is when I type something with the keyboard, the status bar keeps appearing and disappearing with each key stroke.

Comment: On some devices this causes the dialog layout to lose it's width, but keep it's height.  I found that adding this before .show() fixed it even though they were already set in the xml layout.

 dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: In case of DialogFragment's inheritor we need to put `getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` inside `onCreateView`.

Comment: **If you are using AppCompatDialog, then use:** `dialog.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Answer (score 26):

create new style in styles.xml

```
<style name="myDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

then add this to your manifest:

```
 <activity android:name=".youractivity" android:theme="@style/myDialog"></activity>
```

Answer (score 16):

All the above answer not working for me for AppCompatDialog

If you are using **AppCompatDialog** try this

***Important note:*** Set this before calling setContentView.

> dialog.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: Thank you, that was my issue, driving me crazy.

Answer (score 5):

create your XML which is shown in dialog
here it is activity_no_title_dialog

```
final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(context);
dialog1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.activity_no_title_dialog);
dialog1.show();
```

Answer (score 3):

With next variant I have no reaction:

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //before     
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.logindialog);
```

So, I try to use next:

```
dialog.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //before     
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.logindialog);
```

This variant work excellent.

Answer (score 2):

You can also define Theme in android manifest file for not display Title bar..

You just define theme `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"` in activity where u dont want to display title bar

**Example:-**

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"android:targetSdkVersion="4" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".splash"
              android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<activity android:name="main" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"></activity>
```

Comment: I already have an activity without the status bar, but when I'm typing on the virutal keyboard the status bar appears and disappears (pushing all the layout) just like when you start the activity and the status bar disapears. only this time its each time I touch the keyboard

Answer (score 2):

if you are using a custom view then remeber to request window feature before adding content view like this

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(view);
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

use below code before setcontentview :-

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
```

**Note:-** above code must have to use above `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);`

**In XML use a theme**

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

**also styles.xml:**

```
<style name="hidetitle" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And then:

```
Dialog dialog_hidetitle_example = new Dialog(context, R.style.hidetitle);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am an Android novice and came across this question trying to get rid of a title bar.

I'm using an activity and displaying it as a dialog. I was poking around with themes and came across a useful bit of default theming.

Here's the code from my `AndroidManifest.xml` that I was using when the title bar was showing:

```
<activity
    android:name=".AlertDialog"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"

    >

</activity>
```

Here's the change that got me my desired result:

```
<activity
    android:name=".AlertDialog"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar"

    >

</activity>
```

As I said, I'm still new to Android, so this may have undesirable side-effects, but it appears to have given me the outcome I wanted, which was just to remove the title bar from the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

```
**write this before adding view to dialog.**
```

dialog1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Answer (score 1):

I'm using next variant:

**Activity of my custom Dialog:**

```
public class AlertDialogue extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnOk;
    TextView textDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alert_dialogue);

        textDialog = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_dialog) ;
        textDialog.setText("Hello, I'm the dialog text!");

        btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_dialog);
        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_alert_dialogue.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".AlertDialogue">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:text="Hello, I'm the dialog text!"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_dialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="Ok"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_dialog" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Manifest:**

```
<activity android:name=".AlertDialogue"
            android:theme="@style/AlertDialogNoTitle">
</activity>
```

**Style:**

```
<style name="AlertDialogNoTitle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
Dailog dialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.this, R.style.dialogstyle);

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="dialogstyle" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple [android dialog popup library](https://github.com/00ec454/pop). It is very simple to use on your activity.

When submit button is clicked try following code after including above lib in your code

```
Pop.on(this)
   .with()
   .title(R.string.title) //ignore if not needed
   .icon(R.drawable.icon) //ignore if not needed
   .cancelable(false) //ignore if not needed
   .layout(R.layout.custom_pop)
   .when(new Pop.Yah() {
       @Override
       public void clicked(DialogInterface dialog, View view) {
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Yah button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   }).show();
```

Add one line in your gradle and you good to go

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.vistrav:pop:2.0'
}
```