# App name(title) showing in a dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my application i am using an activity as a dialog.Everything works fine but there is one small problem.Whenever the dialog is shown,the title bar is visible.I had done `requestWindowFeature(Window.No.Title)` but still the title bar is comming.
[image]

xml

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: do you placed requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); before onCreate?

Comment: nah before setContentView()

Comment: ok place it before onCreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using wrong theme

use this

```
android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog.NoActionBar
```

also you can hide action bar programmatic .

for that you have to use this in your onCreate mathod

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
}
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
getting this error

Comment: @androGuy the use toolbar http://javatechig.com/android/android-lollipop-toolbar-example

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //before     
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.logindialog);
```

add this before you show the dialog

this answer originally form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263639/android-dialog-removing-title-bar)

Comment: in your code is `requestWindowFeature(Window.No.Title)`