# Hide title when clicked and show other title on popup menu in android

Tags: java, android

I want to hide the title on a `PopupMenu` when clicked and show another title.

My code:

```
dropdown.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            popup = new PopupMenu(mcontext, v);
            MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.jh, popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {  

                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  
                    Menu menu1 = popup.getMenu();
                    if(item.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Add me as Favorite")){
                        menu1.findItem(R.id.one1233).setVisible(false);
                        menu1.findItem(R.id.two).setVisible(true);
                    }
             // Toast.makeText(People_detail.this,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                    Log.i("sdf",item.getTitle().toString());
                    return true;  
                }  
            });  
            popup.show();
                return;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the title of a dialog using:

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

To hide menuitem, try doing

```
menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(false);
```

Please check [Removing title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263639/android-dialog-removing-title-bar)

Comment: No....I dont wont to hide menu but i wont hide  menu Item of 0 th Position and its id is one1233

Comment: try something like--- menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(false);