# How to no title bar AlertDialog on android? (try use requestWindowFeature but no resolve symbol)

Tags: android

when I button Click, show AlertDialog.

but clicked button, show title bar. 
I want remove title bar. so I try

`builder.requestWindowFeature(Window_FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

but `requestWindowFeature` cannot resolve symbol error.

[Android Dialog: Removing title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263639/android-dialog-removing-title-bar)

I reference this site.

but my source not work.
my source not activity only class.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom `Dialog` and use is to show the alert. Something like below should work

```
    Dialog dialogView = new Dialog(mActivity, android.R.style.ThemeDeviceDefaultLightNoActionBar);

    dialogView.setContentView(R.layout.custom_alert_layout);
    dialogView.show();
```

The above will also enable you to make any customizations that you would like your alert to display.

Answer (score 1):

Try instead:

```
builder.requestWindowFeature (Window_FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

use this:

```
builder.supportRequestWindowFeature (Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting the feature on the builder, not on the dialog. call the `requestWindowFeature(Window_FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` after you call the `create()` method on the builder, which returns an `AlertDialog` and then call `requestWindowFeature(Window_FEATURE_NO_TITLE)`. And you should request the feature before setting the view of the dialog. You can request the feature in `onCreate` of the dialog like `getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window_FEATURE_NO_TITLE)`