# How to remove the title in Dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

I created an Activity as a dialog using the code below which I put in my manifest. But the problem is it has Title bar, how can I remove it?

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Comment: What about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644134/android-how-to-create-a-dialog-without-a-title?

Comment: Its Activity that behaves the same as dialog

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if Dialog ..............

```
Dailog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.mydialogstyle);
```

**res-->values-->mydialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="mydialogstyle" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: You have to understand, it is Activity that only behaves the same as Dialog. It is neither Dialog or Alertdialog

Comment: <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item> should set to true

Answer (score 12):

> Use This Code

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.getWindow();
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);       
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
    dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 8):

For Me following worked :

```
<style name="MyActivityDialogTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this code when creating a dialog:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who are using AppCompatActivity, above answers may not work.

**Try this**

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
immediately before setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog_activity);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is work for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <style name="mydialogstyle" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and this

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: both the answers are already posted above you just combined them into one answer

Answer (score 1):

Remove Title Bar from Activity extending **ActionBarActivity** or **AppcompatActivity** with Dialog Theme

```
<style name="Theme.MyDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

It work for me:

In the onCreate() of my custom Dialog Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alert_dialogue);

    //your code....

}
```

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".AlertDialogue"
            android:theme="@style/AlertDialogNoTitle">
</activity>
```

Style:

```
<style name="AlertDialogNoTitle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler _alerthandler = new Handler();
    Runnable _alertrunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ProfileActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Create custom dialog object
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ProfileActivity.this);
                    // Include dialog.xml file
                    dialog.getWindow();
                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alertbox);
                    TextView title = (TextView) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.AlertBox_Title);
                    title.setText(Appconstant.Toast_Title);
                    TextView text = (TextView) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.AlertBox_Msg);
                    text.setText(Appconstant.Toast_Msg);
                    dialog.show();

                    Button declineButton = (Button) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.AlertBox_Ok);
                    // if decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                    declineButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // Close dialog
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I try requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); but not working for me, if you are like me so do this : first Add the following code in your res/values/styles.xml:

```
    <style name="NoTitleDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item></style>
```

Pass the theme to your dialog:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.NoTitleDialog);
```

that's it very simple