# How to change the background of Android Alert Dialog Title

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to change the background of the Alert dialog. I have tried following code piece to do so:

```
 <style name="Theme.AlertDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#659F26</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/Theme.AlertDialog.Title</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.AlertDialog.Title" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/cab_background_top_example</item>
    </style>
```

Java Code:

```
ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper( this, R.style.Theme_AlertDialog);
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);

alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.confirmation));   
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.msg));       
alertDialogBuilder.show();
```

My app is showing dialog like this:

[image]

while i want it to look like:

[image]

Please suggest, what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the title in Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633990/how-to-remove-the-title-in-dialog)

Answer (score 6):

Use this code when creating a dialog:

```
 dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

create your own layout As many customise done with title then set your layout

```
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
```

**NOTE:** use

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); before     
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
```

otherwise it give error.

Answer (score 0):

```
ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper( this, R.style.Theme_AlertDialog);
```

In this line use  instead of "`this`" use `ActivityName.this`

Comment: This is not a solution to OP's problem.