# How to remove header of dialog in Android

Tags: android, header, dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How to create a Dialog without a title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644134/android-how-to-create-a-dialog-without-a-title)

How I can remove the title header from dialog in Android, which is in Gray colour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case if you aren't extending.
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

In case if you are extending the Class from Dialog:

this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

It will help you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks!! for more descriptive definition.

Comment: Just a caution, it should be called before setting the content to dialog.

Answer (score 1):

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, FEATURE_NO_TITLE works when creating a dialog,

```
  Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
  dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```