# White rectangle on top of DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-studio

When using a dialogFragment I get a white space rectangle at the top of the fragment without knowing why.

What I should get [image]

What I actually get [image]

My DialogFragment:

```
 public class SelectDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //inflate layout with recycler view
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.select_frag, container, false);
            return v;
        }

}
```

select_frag.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set style without title:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
}
```

Also you can found more useful example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277460/how-to-create-a-dialogfragment-without-title)

Comment: I haven't specified any specific theme

Comment: Oh yes, you should set `STYLE_NO_TITLE` style.

Comment: Unfortunately the white bar is still there