# Android fragment inflated from layout resource showing an extra strip at the top

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, android-cardview

I am trying to create an Internet connectivity error dialog box. I have the dialogFragment code for it, which inflates a layout. The problem is, the layout appears fine in the android studio, but on the phone, it appears with an extra horizontal strip on the top.[image: The snapshot of the dialog box on the phone]

[image: The snap of the dialog box in Android Studio]

This is the layout code :

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
style="@style/Animation.AppCompat.Dialog">


<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<RadioButton
    android:text="RadioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone please help me understand why I am getting this extra strip. I tried putting CardView and other layouts instead of LinearLayout, but the strip seems to be something beyond the layout file. I cannot access or modify it.

Comment: [This would be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15279400/6213557)

Comment: @RishabhDuttSharma That helped a lot. God, libraries can be painful at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

DialogFragment has a default divider on top. 
You can remove the divider with following code -

int dividerID = dialog.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", "id", "android");
View divider = dialog.findViewById(dividerID);
 You can then set height to 0 or transparent color to the view.