# DialogFragment design is looking okay in KitKat and under

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment

So, I created some dialogs that are displaying okay on Android 5.0 and above.
However when I tested this on Android Kitkat they are showing a white square above the whole content. Here are examples of what's happening. And this is the code of the dialog with the light blue header.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="350dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/time_picker_background"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/park_button"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Titulo -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vehicle_create_title"
        style="@style/AlertDialog.TextView.InverseTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/alert_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/alert_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/alert_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/alert_vertical_margin"
        android:text="Agregar una tarjeta" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_credit_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- Card number -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_card_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_card_number"
            style="@style/Login.EditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:hint="Número de tarjeta"
            android:maxLength="19"
            android:inputType="phone">
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_scan_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        android:onClick="onScanPress"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_card_exp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- Card expiration date -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_card_exp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_card_exp"
            style="@style/Login.EditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:hint="Fecha de Vencimiento"
            android:maxLength="5"
            android:inputType="phone">
        </EditText>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_cvv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <!-- Card CVVV -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_card_cvv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_card_cvv"
            style="@style/Login.EditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:hint="CVV"
            android:maxLength="4"
            android:inputType="phone">
        </EditText>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_submit_card"
    android:theme="@style/ConfirmSession.Button.Cancel"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/btn_confirm_session_accept" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The code of the one with the green message is this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/transaction_success"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white_w_transparency"
android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/transaction_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transaction_success"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/transaction_success" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vehicle_create_title"
                style="@style/AlertDialog.TextView.InverseTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Transacción aceptada" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/transaction_information"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                style="@style/TextViewDefault.bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_layout_padding"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_layout_padding"
                android:text="Tu compra fue realizada con éxito" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_layout_padding"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_layout_padding">
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/TextViewSmallDefault"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Número de tarjeta: " />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cardNumber"
                        style="@style/TextViewSmallDefault.bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="1234 5678 9102 3456" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_layout_padding"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_layout_padding">
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/TextViewSmallDefault"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Código de autorización: " />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/authCode"
                        style="@style/TextViewSmallDefault.bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="001533" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_layout_padding"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_layout_padding">
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/TextViewSmallDefault"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Id de transacción: " />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/idTransaction"
                        style="@style/TextViewSmallDefault.bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="2455" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_layout_padding"
                android:background="@color/light_gray"
                    />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_layout_padding"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_layout_padding">
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/TextViewSmallDefault"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Monto: " />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/amount"
                        style="@style/TextViewSmallDefault.bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="c1000" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/default_layout_padding"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_layout_padding">
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/TextViewSmallDefault"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Balance actual: " />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/balance"
                        style="@style/TextViewSmallDefault.bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="c5.000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_accept"
                        android:theme="@style/AlertDialog.Button.Accept"
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                        android:background="@color/park_button"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"

android:text="@string/btn_confirm_session_accept" />

             </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: DialogFragmentExample on Kitkat]

[image: DialogFragmentExample on Kitkat]

Comment: try showing your layout bounds via developer options and seeing if the layout actually covers that area. I haven't used DialogFragments much but I feel like that might be excess space for a dialog title. And lastly, maybe consider wrap_content for heights rather than match_parent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a DialogFragment without title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277460/how-to-create-a-dialogfragment-without-title)