# Editset custom layout title for my dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

i want have my custom header for my `CustomAlert`.
what do i do for my custom layout for Dialog,s title?

Edit2:
i added my code:

```
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
        {           
            switch(id)
            {           
            case Dialog_Reset :     
            Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.about);  
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);         
            return dialog;
            }
            return super.onCreateDialog(id);
       }
```

and becuse i dont like default header in dialog,i remove it now,while i learn having my custom header.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644134/android-how-to-create-a-dialog-without-a-title

Answer (score 1):

> but i dont understand what is "titleId". is it what really? is it my
>   special layout designed that i want use for title?

`titleId` : title identifier in other words a string resource identifier, e.g. `R.string.app_name`. You can add these in `strings.xml` found at `res` > `values` folders

Android Dev Doc: [Dialog.setTitle (int titleId)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setTitle%28int%29)

*More about string resources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493287/android-how-do-i-get-string-from-resources-using-its-name)*

Comment: i want have my custom header for dialog

Answer (score 0):

You can set `CustomTitle` of your `Alert Dialog` using `public AlertDialog.Builder setCustomTitle (View customTitleView)` method.

As per documentation

> public AlertDialog.Builder setCustomTitle (View customTitleView)

Set the title using the custom view customTitleView. The methods setTitle(int) and setIcon(int) should be sufficient for most titles, but this is provided if the title needs more customization. Using this will replace the title and icon set via the other methods.

Parameters
customTitleView The custom view to use as the title.
Returns
This Builder object to allow for chaining of calls to set methods

example

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)yourClass.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View yourView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);

AlertDialog.Builder ab= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
ab.setCustomTitle(yourView);
ab.setMessage(message);
...


 ab.create();
 ab.show();
```

for details see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html)

Comment: but waht is "your view"

Comment: @setareshojaei `yourView` is a custom view which you want to show in title.

Comment: i want have a title with my layout.is it my xml view id?

Comment: and Dialog dialog=new Dialog() that dialog dosnt has setCustomTitle method. i put my code in Edit