# How to remove Alert dialog Title bar

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am following [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/android-dialog-android-custom-dialog.html) code to create custom dialog but i am not getting how to remove dialog title bar ?

```
  AlertDialog alertDialog;

   @Override
   protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

      AlertDialog dialogDetails = null;

      switch (id) {
      case DIALOG_LOGIN:

       LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
       View dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);

           AlertDialog.Builder dialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
           dialogbuilder.setTitle("Login");
           dialogbuilder.setView(dialogview);
           dialogDetails = dialogbuilder.create();

           break;
          }

      return dialogDetails;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {

      switch (id) {
      case DIALOG_LOGIN:
      alertDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;

      .......

}
```

I know to remove title area of the Alert Dialog, we have to use `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

But don't know where i have to place above line ?

Comment: Just remove setTitle(-) then there is no title bar.

Comment: Use this , dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); before     
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.logindialog);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to create a Dialog without a title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644134/android-how-to-create-a-dialog-without-a-title)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you don't want title bar in alert dialog then just remove below line from code.

```
dialogbuilder.setTitle("Login");
```

If still not working then add below line.

```
dialogbuilder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: what if i want my text should look same in both (phone and tablet) ?

Comment: You can also create custom dialog.

Comment: hey bro this time i am not talking about custom alert dialog, i am concern about how to show text always of same size in both devices phones and tablets

Comment: we can't customize default alert dialog. so you have to create custom dialog for that.

Comment: bro pls try to understand my point, i am not talking about dialog here, my question is like in my activity i have text view with text as "Hello World" and i want it should look same sizes on all devices (phones/tabs)

Comment: @Sun hmm, use SP dimension & stop chat here

Comment: Not sure why this was selected as the correct answer. When using this answer, the title text is indeed gone, but the very noticeable big white TITLE BAR still remains. The answer the others have posted (... FEATURE_NO_TITLE ... ) works to completely remove the title bar (and title text).

Comment: If use custom layout, must add `dialogbuilder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before `setContentView` instead.

Answer (score 19):

Use `dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.logindialog);` by doing so you will be able to hide the `Dialog`'s title.

Answer (score 4):

Use `dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Answer (score 2):

First remove this line:

```
dialogbuilder.setTitle("Login");
```

Then add this one:

```
dialogbuilder.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove

```
dialogbuilder.setTitle("Login");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
AlertDialog alertDialog;

Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
        mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,
        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Hello, this is a custom dialog!");
ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);

builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setView(layout);
alertDialog = builder.create();
```

[Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644134/android-how-to-create-a-dialog-without-a-title)

Answer (score 1):

I could not find `.requestWindowFeature` with AlertDialog Builder.

If you do not want to have a title when constructing an Alert Dialog with a Builder, use `new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth);`

Answer (score 0):

Eventually on a Motorola Droid Razr M (AOS 4.4) smartphone these approaches does not work and I believe there are other smatphones like this exist on a market. The only effect gained from:

```
        setTitle(null);
        setCustomTitle(null);
```

is that title has no text but its view still persists in the dialog view (looks like an empty view at a top). So the only way I found is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161994/how-to-get-the-alertdialog-title):

```
        int titleId = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier( "alertTitle", "id", "android" );
        if (titleId > 0) {
            View dialogTitle = findViewById(titleId);
            if (dialogTitle != null) {
                ((View)dialogTitle.getParent().getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use Dialog with a custom layout it will definitely work**

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_layout);
            Button btOk = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btOk);
            Button btCancel = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btCancel);
            btOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //To Do
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            btCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
```

**custom_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btOk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Ok" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cancel" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing a theme to your dialog can remove the title bar for you.

```
<style name="NoTitleDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Pass the theme to your dialog:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.NoTitleDialog);
```

Answer (score -6):

Use this

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
           dialogbuilder .requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
           dialogbuilder.setView(dialogview);
           dialogDetails = dialogbuilder.create();
```

Comment: "dialogbuilder.requestWindowFeature" isn't supported.

Comment: Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: @AshishJohn: Read the full question and title before commenting anythng rubbish! Alert Dialogue and Dialogue are two different classes

Comment: @BhavikMehta Given question is "....but i am not getting how to remove dialog title bar"; & I have proposed solution to remove dialog title bar... I think you read only the code where its written "Alert Dialogue" & not the question