# How to remove strange border from DialogFragment with AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to implement AlertDialog based on DialogFragment with this code:

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("title")
                .setMessage("message")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                })
                .create();
    }
}
```

It working well, but I get a strange white border around AlertDialog:

[image]

How to remove this border (preferably programmatically)?

**UPDATE**: my styles.xml contains this code:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/MyDialogTheme</item>
</style>        

<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"></style>
```

When I remove `<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/MyDialogTheme</item>` row, this issue is gone away. But I need this row because I want to customize AlertDialog. How to fix this style?

Comment: Can you please post your code where you are using this `Dialog Fragment`? @BArtWell

Comment: @Pooja, I am calling it by code `new AlertDialogFragment().show(getFragmentManager(), "TAG_HERE");`.

Comment: Already answered 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644134/android-how-to-create-a-dialog-without-a-title

Comment: @Don here question is different

Comment: @BArtWell your code working fine at my end.

Comment: I think the problem is related to ur fragment manger or getActivity, what ever you posted code snipet is proper.

Comment: @Pooja, I update question. Here is new facts about issue.

Comment: I am having this same issue. Did you figure out a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

I have just checked your code ,but have not get any issue like this.
I call the class like

```
   package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class A extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        AlertDialogFragment al=new AlertDialogFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        al.show(fm, "test");


    }


class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle("title")
                    .setMessage("message")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    })
                    .create();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: use new support library
  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog.html