# Remove title from dialog in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

How to remove the title of the custome dialog.
And also remove its space.
Thankyou.
My layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="top" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="78dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:text="Click to the button "
    android:textColor="#ffff00"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

my code

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setTitle("Daialos");

    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();
```

i am using
     dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
to avoid the title but its only avoid the text not the space.

Comment: where is your question?

Comment: i want remove my custom dialoge titile

Comment: post your code first for dialog

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644134/android-how-to-create-a-dialog-without-a-title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644134/android-how-to-create-a-dialog-without-a-title)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you set a title for your dialog and you already want to remove the title? You should do something like this:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash, null)
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.setContentView(view);
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

remove line  dialog.setTitle().
 then it works fine.